# Prepared Statement with ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: php, mysql

I think this one should be pretty easy but I am having trouble getting it right.  I have searched a bit but being new to prepared statements I can't quite figure out the syntax from looking at other examples I have found here and elsewhere.  Anyhow here is my code.

```
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO user_info (city, state, website, public_contact, user, zipcode, pic, emailme) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (city, state, website, public_contact, user, zipcode, pic, emailme) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)")) {
    $stmt -> bind_param("sssssssi",$city, $state, $website, $public_contact, $user, $zipcode, $pic, $emailme);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($result);
    $stmt -> close();
}
```

user is the unique.  This IMO is just a syntax problem so could somebody help me out with the correct syntax?  Much appreciated.

ETA: just to help trouble shooting this does work as intended when I remove the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  part but obviously, it only allows the one record per user and will not update

UPDATE:  was never able to find a working syntax to use the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE so what I did instead (admittedly probably not the most efficient way) was check the table before hand for the user.  If the user exist I run and UPDATE, if not I run a INSERT.  Below is my working code.  Hope this helps somebody who gets stuck in my situation.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user='$user'";

 if ($result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql))
 {
 /* Return the number of rows in result set */
 $rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 /* Free result set */
 mysqli_free_result($result);
 } 

 if($rows == 0) { 
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO user_info (city, state, website, public_contact, user, zipcode, pic, emailme) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?) ")) {

$stmt -> bind_param("sssssssi",$city, $state, $website, $public_contact, $user, $zipcode, $pic, $emailme);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($result);
$stmt -> close();
}

} else {

if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("UPDATE user_info SET city=?, state=?, website=?, public_contact=?, zipcode=?, pic=?, emailme=? WHERE user='$user'")) {

$stmt -> bind_param("ssssssi",$city, $state, $website, $public_contact, $zipcode, $pic, $emailme);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($result);
$stmt -> close();
}
    }
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The easiest way to use INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is to use the VALUES clause in the following way, so you don't need to repeat the parameters in the UPDATE clause. They just use the same values for each column that you passed in the VALUES clause:

```
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("
    INSERT INTO user_info (city, state, website, public_contact, 
        user, zipcode, pic, emailme)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        city = VALUES(city),
        state = VALUES(state),
        website = VALUES(website),
        public_contact = VALUES(public_contact),
        user = VALUES(user),
        zipcode = VALUES(zipcode),
        pic = VALUES(pic),
        emailme = VALUES(emailme)") {
    $stmt -> bind_param("sssssssi",$city, $state, $website, $public_contact, 
        $user, $zipcode, $pic, $emailme);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> close();
}
```

The IODKU syntax requires that you set each column individually. You can't list them all in one clause like you were trying to do.

You should always report any errors from any call to prepare() or execute(). Or you can make mysqli throw exceptions:

```
$mysqli -> report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT;
```

Also, you don't need to bind_result(), since there is no result set from INSERT:

```
// NO: $stmt -> bind_result($result);
```

Comment: Thankyou!  this was exactly what I was looking for.  You the man Bill!

Comment: I've edited MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL to change it to MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT. The former generates errors that should be warnings.

Comment: The issue I was having was I was still getting inserts, causing duplicate records. I set the field as a unique index and now the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is working.

Comment: Yes, if there is no conflict with a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY column, then as far as MySQL is concerned, it's not a duplicate. It's just another row with the same value in some column.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that this syntax is preferable to the REPLACE INTO syntax. Although the result of the operation is the same, the way it works is slightly different. REPLACE INTO checks if a record with the corresponding primary key already exists. In this case it will be deleted first and then inserted again. This can lead to hard to find errors when using foreign key relationships, which I unfortunately had to experience painfully myself.

Comment: INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE on the other hand does what the name promises. It checks if the primary key already exists and if so the field values specified in the UPDATE clause are updated. Contrary to a "normal" update clause, however, no WHERE condition must be specified here, since this is set automatically internally.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderBehling, I agree with that! REPLACE even activates the DELETE trigger and then the INSERT trigger on the table, if they exist. IODKU actives either the INSERT or the UPDATE trigger, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest having a look at something like [Doctrine DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html) (not ORM) - it allows you to heave key => value pairs and makes these types of operations easier to wield when there's so many values.

You can then do something like:

```
try {
    $conn->insert(
    'db.`table`',
     [
       'city' => $city,
       'state' => $state
     ]);
} catch (Exception $e) {

    if( $e->getCode() !== '23000' ) {
        throw $e;
    }

    $conn->update(
    'db.`table`',
     [
       'city' => $city,
       'state' => $state
     ],
     [
       'user' => $user
     ]);
}
```

Comment: This is probably a great answer but I have to admit is way way way over my head.  Lets ignore all of the values and pretend it is just the values user (the unique) and city?  How would my syntax be for that?   Thanks thinice

Comment: @ButterDog I updated the example a bit - The DBAL takes care of the escaping for you, no need to bind using the built ins.

Comment: I really appreciate the help thinice but this code just doesn't make any sense to me, I mean, I can kinda follow the logic but it is just past my level of PHP mastery.