# Update on duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

In my `User` table I have `phone` as unique. So when I insert duplicate phone number I want to update `deviceId`, `registrationId` and I want the `id` which got updated. I tried this but its not working.

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("INSERT into User (name,phone, deviceId,registrationId) values(:name,:phone, :deviceId,:registrationId)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE deviceId = :deviceId, registrationId = :registrationId, id=lastInsertId(id)");
```

Thank you..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prepared Statement with ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699598/prepared-statement-with-on-duplicate-key)

Comment: what is your primery key? i guess on duplicate update is work with primary key, try to set phone number is your primary key then try.

Comment: As long as your "phone" value is Unique/Primary and as stated in the mysql documentation this should work "INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;" ..

Comment: You have to add constraint in your table ON UPDATE to NO ACTION for the foreign key.

Comment: my primary key is id. and phone is unique

Comment: phone is unique but its not a primary. i have id as primary key

Comment: Can you be more specific because "its not working" is not very clear. Is the on duplicate not triggering, is the id not returning? What?

Comment: when i try to insert duplicate phone its not getting updated in database

Comment: What is not getting updated? deviceId and registrationId? Is a new record being inserted instead?

Comment: when phone number is already present then deviceId and registrationId should get updated but its not getting updated

Comment: Can you paste the results of the query `show create table User`. Also, is your query returning an error message (use `print_r($db->errorInfo());`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93463/discussion-between-dotcomly-and-shridhar-patil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chatting with the OP the problem was he was not getting the ID when a record was updated. The final solution is to use `id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` so the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will set the id and then  fetch the id with `$db->lastInsertId();`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT into User (name,phone, deviceId,registrationId) values(:name, :phone, :deviceId,:registrationId)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE deviceId = :deviceId, registrationId = :registrationId, id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)");
```

Then fetch the insert id after.

```
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```