# Edit duplicate if exists mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have some troubles with my mysqli INSERT code.
I don't really know how to deal with duplicates but I have read many posts there and I tryied to get it work, but when I execute this code with same variables the count of rows increases. Can you please help me fixing this code or find another way to check for duplicates?

```
  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }


  if ($stmt = $conn->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO matka (jmeno, prijmeni, bydliste, telefon, email)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    jmeno = VALUES(jmeno),
    prijmeni = VALUES(prijmeni),
    bydliste = VALUES(bydliste),
    telefon = VALUES(telefon),
    email = VALUES(email)" )) {
  $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $jmeno_matky, $prijmeni_matky, $bydliste_matky, $telefon_matky, $email_matky);
  $stmt->execute();
  printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
  $stmt->close();
  $id_matky = $conn->insert_id;
  $conn->close();
  }
```

Comment: I've never seen the `prijmeni = VALUES()` syntax before, that works? Also if just updating to the same data I'd just ignore, `insert ignore`.

Comment: I was it there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699598/prepared-statement-with-on-duplicate-key

His code looked similar as mine so i gave it a try. Should i then use instead of INSERT INTO tablename (...) - INSERT IGNORE tablename (..)??

Comment: The `insert ignore` just ignores the errors you'd get on the duplicate attempt. If you don't have uniques though that wont throw an error. Make something unique there so you know when a dup shouldnt occur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` relies on there being a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key defined. This means that the column(s) the key is defined on cannot be the same for two rows.

If you for example made an UNIQUE key on `email` like so:

`CREATE INDEX matka_email ON matka (email)`

then when you try and insert a record and the email address already exists, it will update the fields as defined in your query after `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

Note that Unique keys can involve several columns like so:

`CREATE INDEX matka_alldata ON matka (jmeno, prijmeni, bydliste, telefon, email)`

See docs:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Comment: Oh thank you, I thought I can use it just to check if all data exist. Do you know how should I check if the values already exists? It would help me a lot.

Comment: You could create a unique key across all fields - I will update the answer with an example